# Changing Actionbar Overflow Icon in code: weird resizing

Tags: java, android, svg, icons, android-actionbar

**Goal**:

Changing the actionbar's overflow item icon to another color.
The new icon should be input via svg.

**State**:

Note that the overflow icon is replace with a refresh icon to examine the size differences. It will be replaced with the overflow icon later. Both icons are loaded using the same method, with the same parameter, from the [same .svg file](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/5Rm5sCm/0/blob?download).
I use [svg-android-2](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android-2/) for .svg loading and rendering.
[image: Current state]

**Modification code**:

Please don't discuss the danger of using this reflective code before having solved the problem :)

```
// http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/internal/app/ActionBarImpl.java/
private void hackOverflowIcon() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    if (actionBar.getClass().getName().equals("com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl")) {
        try {
            Field actionBarViewField = actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mActionView");
            actionBarViewField.setAccessible(true);
            Object actionBarView = actionBarViewField.get(actionBar);

            Field actionMenuViewField = actionBarView.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mActionMenuPresenter");
            actionMenuViewField.setAccessible(true);
            Object actionMenu = actionMenuViewField.get(actionBarView);

            Field overFlowViewField = actionMenu.getClass().getDeclaredField("mOverflowButton");
            overFlowViewField.setAccessible(true);
            ImageButton overFlowView = (ImageButton) overFlowViewField.get(actionMenu);

            Drawable drawable=SVGUtils.getDrawableFromRaw(this, R.drawable.refresh, new RectF(0, 0, 120, 120));
            overFlowView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Actionbar is an instance of " + actionBar.getClass().getName());
}
```

**Question**:

Why do the icons have different sizes and how can I prevent the size changes?

Thanks for reading and for any help on this problem,
Till